# Android - Resize content when softkeyoard shows in a Dialog subclass

Tags: android, forms, android-activity, keyboard, scrollview

I have a Dialog subclass which I used for form-styled input (i.e. lots of text fields and buttons).  This is backed by a Scrollview, however when the keyboard shows - the scrollview doesn't resize with it. 
I see on an Activity, you can set android:windowSoftInputMode in the manififest, but how can this work for dialog subclasses?  Do I need to manually resize the scrollview when the keyboard appears/disappears?

Thanks,